# What's the shortcut for "Deselect Layers" in Photoshop?

Tags: adobe-photoshop

What's the shortcut for "Deselect Layers" in Photoshop (in OS X)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Windows it is not set by default in CS5. To see if it is set in OS X, go to the Keyboard Shortcuts menu:

[image: Keyboard Shortcuts]

If it is not set, you can set it to something that would work well for you.