# Deselect layers in Photoshop

Tags: adobe-photoshop, shortcuts

[There's already a post similar to this](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/13428/whats-the-shortcut-for-deselect-layers-in-photoshop), which describes there is no built in shortcut to deselect multiple layers, but I can clarify my problem a bit.

`control` + `click` will select a layer in Photoshop. `control` + `shift` + `click` will select multiple layers.

However, after i've selected multiple layers, if I try `control` + `click` again on a single layer, it won't deselect those multiple layers and only select the one layer.

Is there some way around this, such as by deselecting a layer with some key combination, or something? I don't want to resort to custom keyboard shortcuts. I want to have a fast workflow using Photoshop on anyone's desk.

Comment: So let me get this straight... You have found a solution, but you don't want to "resort to custom keyboard shortcuts", so that doesn't work for you? Alright… Secondly, if you can select with `ctrl+click` but you can't deselect with it, then something is wrong with your photoshop.

Answer (score 3):

> ... Deselect those multiple layers and only select the one layer

If you only want to select one layer:

- Click on the layer
- Good times commence
- Only one layer is selected
- Woohoo

[image: NO CONTROL]

In all seriousness though...

Am I missing something here?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if i got your question right, but using command+click (which is equivalent to ctrl+click on windows) it will deselect that one layer, but only if he's been selected before. You can deselect multiple layers by using shift+click but it will deselect every single layer from that layer on, you can't draw an area - as far as i know.

Answer (score 0):

I know exactly what you are referring to and I also find it frustrating. I don't like to go to the layer panel and click on each layer i want to edit. That dude that answered with a gif didn't read your comment at all. I usually Ctrl + click on several layers at a time and deselecting all of them wasn't easy.

Ctrl+Click will unhighlight all layers and you can just Ctrl+Click to select the one you want to modify again. That really is the easiest way.

Answer (score 0):

This is for Illustrator did not check if it also works in photoshop but I assume it to be the same.

I managed to find the solution after this topic didn't give me the answer.
Holding <kbd>Shift</kbd> and clicking on the green squire enables deselecting.

What I mean by enable is that holding <kbd>Shift</kbd> and pressing the circle before it does not work at first.

After deselecting a layer on the green square only then does <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>L Click</kbd> also deselect a layer on the circle.

Not really important but try looking for the difference as for now Shift +L mouse on the green squire selects or deselects a layer.

Answer (score -1):

Ctrl + click in the document window and outside the canvas area with the move tool. This will deselect all the layers.